# How To Keep page from losing formatting when adding hidden span?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got an asp.net mvc4 razor page that has a for loop around conference sessions.  On each iteration, I want to dump some hidden data in so that I can do searches. The problem is, when I dump this hidden data in, it breaks my formatting and the page goes askew.  Any suggestions on how to stop that from happening? I thought a span with style="visibility: hidden" would effectively not impact my screen by it does.

You can see below where I have the offending code commented out.  When I uncomment it, the page displays correctly.

```
<div id="currentSession">
    <span id="sortsessionTitle"><span id="sessionTitle_@session.Id"  
                                        title="@session.Title">@session.TitleEllipsized</span>

    </span>
    <br />
    <i>by</i>
    @{ var multipleSpeakerSeparator = " "; }
    @foreach (var speaker in session.SpeakersList)
    {
        @multipleSpeakerSeparator
        <a href="@(speaker.SpeakerLocalUrl)" class="author" 
            id="speaker_@(speaker.AttendeeId)" 
            speakerId="@speaker.AttendeeId"> @speaker.UserFirstName @speaker.UserLastName </a>
        multipleSpeakerSeparator = ",";
    }
    @*<span style="visibility: hidden;">

        @foreach (var speaker in session.SpeakersList)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(speaker.Company))
            {
                @speaker.Company;
            }
        }
        @session.TagListArrayString
    </span>*@

    @if (Model.ShowAgendaOnSchedule)
    {
        <span id="spanSessionTime"> @session.SessionTime &nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    }

    @if (Model.ShowRoomOnSchedule)
    {
        <span id="spanSessionRoom"> Room: @session.RoomNumber </span>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Try style="display:none" instead of style="visibility:hidden"

Comment: Thanks Nathan! you are magical. Not only did you answer it 7 hours before I asked it, but you got it right.  My hat is off. (now it is showing 20 minutes ago, but my hat is still off).